# How to generate filter elements w.r.t table column definitions for all the tables in the website - Angular

Tags: angular, architecture, angular-components, tablefilter

I'm setting up a new table filter popup component, that should be generic and used for all the tables inside my website. I did it dynamically and deleted( not satisfied). Because, ease of use is bit difficult. How to create this component so that it can be easily configurable and usable through out the application (easy to configure). I am attaching the requirement in images. please check once.

My question is x component is having different data type table columns compare to y component table columns. Then how to write generic code to make the filter components elements such as textboxes,radio Buttons ,check boxes ,date range elements and search criteria as ( contains, equal to ,starts with). How to write?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

user [popover](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples) component define UI in it. user service to open service. create callback method. when user select filter and press apply return value in callback method apply in compoent

Comment: My question is x component is having different data type column compare to y component. Then how to write generic or optimized code to make the filter component elements such as radio Buttons ,check boxes ,date range elements and search criteria as ( contains, equal to ,starts with). How to write neatly.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to create a filter Component as a sharable / reusable component

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-filter',
 templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./filter.component.scss']
})
export class FilterComponent {

  @Input() filterOptions: any[];

  @Output() selectedFilteredOptions = new EventEmitter();

}
```

> In xComponent template

```
<app-filter 
   (selectedFilteredOptions)="onApplyFilters()"                                
   [filterOptions]="xOptionsList">
 </app-filter>
```

> In Y Component template

```
 <app-filter 
   (selectedFilteredOptions)="onApplyFilters()"                                
   [filterOptions]="yOptionsList">
 </app-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this. My question is x component is having different data type column compare to y component. Then how to write generic or optimised code to make the filter component elements such as radio Buttons check boxes date range elelemts and search criteria as contains, equal to and end